# Formato de Fecha en @Html.DropDownList - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, linq, datetime

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Como puedo aplicarle un formato decha dentro de un `DropList` intente con un `select` pero sale sin los `0` [`01/02/2020` => `1/02/2020`]

```
ViewBag.evento_horario_id = new SelectList(db.tb_evento_horario_colaborador.Where(a=>a.evento_id==id)
                .Select(a => new { id = a.id, fecha = a.fecha }).ToList(), "id", "fecha");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si no uso `select` me muestra en un formato `MM/dd/yyy` y en `12H`

```
ViewBag.evento_horario_id = new SelectList(db.tb_evento_horario_colaborador.Where(a=>a.evento_id==id)  , "id", "fecha");
```

Y por esto es que le pongo un format creando una nueva lista pero me arroja el error mostrado al inicio

```
ViewBag.evento_horario_id = new SelectList(db.tb_evento_horario_colaborador.Where(a=>a.evento_id==id)
                                                        .Select(a => new { id = a.id, fecha = a.fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") })
                                                        .ToList(), "id", "fecha");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder utilizar el método `ToString()` de .NET, primero tienes que obtener los resultados desde la BD en un objeto en memoria, o sea, debes hacer el `Tolist()` **antes** del `Select()`.

De esta manera, debería funcionar:

```
ViewBag.evento_horario_id = new SelectList(db.tb_evento_horario_colaborador
                            .Where(a => a.evento_id == id)
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(a => new { id = a.id, fecha = a.fecha.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") })
                            .ToList()
                            , "id", "fecha");
```